# Validating a last name with one space or hyphen

Tags: forms, validation

Im trying to find the right Validation Expression in the RegularExpression Validator, but i just can't. I want to validate a text box for Last name to be:
2 - 11 chars, only one space OR hyphen, and Hebrew only.
Can someone please help me with that?